# Resize badge of embedded code

Tags: html

I copied code from a wedding website for a badge to be used on my website. but when i paste the code on my website, the badge is way too large. Can someone tell me how I can modify the code to make this badge smaller, say 30 px x 30 px?

```
<script src='//www.weddingwire.com/assets/vendor/widgets/ww-rated-2013-
d545585beb7833eec3a4dc56cbb3224c.js' type='application/javascript'></script>
<div id='ww-widget-wwrated-2013'>
  <a class="ww-top" 
     target="_blank"  
     title="Weddings, Wedding, Wedding Venues" 
     href="https://www.weddingwire.com"></a>
  <a class="ww-bottom" 
     target="_blank" 
     title="Valerie Saint Martin, Harpist &amp; Opera Singer Reviews, Santa Barbara, Ventura, San Luis Obispo Ceremony 
Music"
     href="https://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/valerie-saint-martin-
harpist-opera-singer-santa-barbara/43cedd5bf13ab414.html"></a>
</div>
<script>   
WeddingWire.ensureInit(function(){
  WeddingWire.createWWRated2013({"vendorId":"43cedd5bf13ab414"}); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the css?  Looks for me like the Css is loading via JavaScript

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: HI, the site wedding wire, just provides this code (i posted above) to copy to your personal website. When I copy the code into my website, the badge is huge. Is there  any way I can modify the code to make the badge a smaller size?